# Como utilizo la clase Date en un constructor?

Tags: java, date, calendar

Estoy haciendo un control de inventarios en Java y quiero añadirle una fecha de caducidad usando la clase Date, cual es la mejor manera de implementarla? Estoy usando un ArrayList para añadir los productor al inventario.
Ya lo he realizado, les dejo el Codigo.
Constructor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar que el atributo today esta declarado como tipo Calendar

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Para que la pregunta sea bien aceptada, debe de ir acompañada del código que has intentado. [ask] y también puede serte de interés realizar el [tour].

Comment: Como sugerencia, si estás haciendo un sistema nuevo te recomiendo usar las clases del package java.time introducidas en java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres tener el miembro que contenga la caducidad en tu clase siendo de tipo Date y se defina en el Constructor, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
  class Producto{
    private Date caducidad;

    public Producto(Date caducidad){
       this.caducidad = caducidad;
    }
  }
```

Esa sería la forma de administrar la caducidad de cada producto, luego si quieres acceder a ella tendrías que tener un método estilo:

```
public Date getCaducidad(){
  return caducidad;
}
```

Y desde tu clase Inventario, llamar a la caducidad de un producto en específico así:

```
Producto producto = listaDeProductos.get(0);
producto.getCaducidad();
```